# How to convert percent slope to degree

Tags: c#, .net

double mypercentslope = 1

With a calculator if I wanted to convert that to a degree, I'd simply do: arctan(0.01);

I've tried Math.Atan(0.01) and it's reporting an incorrect value. I've read that c# uses radians but not sure, based on that, how to accomplish what i need. Thanks all!

Comment: What is the value that you get and what is the value that you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Math.Atan` does give it's result in radians ([from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan(v=vs.110).aspx)). You could use this to convert to degrees:

```
private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
{
   return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

(the above code snippet is taken [from here](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_net_angles.php))

so full working code might look like:

```
double myPercentSlope = 100;

double rads = Math.Atan(myPercentSlope/100);

double degrees = rads * (180.0 / Math.PI);
```

Comment: Thanks Simon... I was overthinking it.